# why didn't Void remain as Void forever?

Tags: universe

Before the Universe..
it was always void.
Void has no beginning.
In-fact only Void can have no beginning.
Because only something that does not exist... can be beginning-less.

the question is..
why didn't it permanently remain.. stay..  as void ?

shouldn't it have permanently.. remained.. stayed.. as void.. ?

wouldn't it only be logical for it to remain.. stay... as void.. forever ?

How can some concept without a beginning have an ending ?

How can Void.. which has no beginning.. have an ending ?

When the Universe came into existence.. isn't that like.. Void.. coming to an end ?

this simply makes no sense .

Void should have permanenty remained as void.
because it is begining less.